# Powershell: Add function into command line without variable

Tags: powershell

Is it somehow possible in powershell to skip variables and include the driveletter function directly in the path of executing the command?

```
. (Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel myHDD).DriveLetter:\temp\ps.ps1
```

The command should look like:

. D:\temp\ps.ps1

When I run it in powershell, I get this error:

```
. : The term 'D' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

At line:1 char:3

- . (Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel myHDD).DriveLetter:\temp ...
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try ```. "$((Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel myHDD).DriveLetter):\temp\ps.ps1"``` - it's explained in the first few sections of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7#variable-substitution

Comment: Thanks, this works! But isn't there a way without the $ sign?

Comment: "dot sourcing" (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) takes a *string* for the path of the script. In your case, the ```$( ... )``` in the string invokes "command substitution" (from the previous link) inside a double-quoted string to substitute a command with its value. I don't think there's a way to do this in a string without the leading ```$```. Is there a specific reason you're trying to avoid the ```$```?

Comment: Yes, I use a powershell script to generate new powershell code (no need to explain further as this can't be changed/influenced), but there's an issue when I use $ and escaping with `doesn't work in my case...

Comment: You could try string concatenation then - something like ```. ((Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel myHDD).DriveLetter + “:\temp\ps.ps1”)```. I can’t test that myself right now, but it *should* work...

Comment: You can also use the `-f` format operator like `. ('{0}:\temp\ps.ps1' -f (Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel myHDD).DriveLetter)`